# I need the playbook to check if the path from the list exists, and if it exists, then it would copy the file using it

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, ansible-awx

I need the playbook to check if the path from the list exists, and if it exists, then it would copy the file using it

```
vars:
   array_path:
     - /opt/1/1/data/123/
     - /opt/2/2/data/234/
     - /opt/3/3/data/345/
     - /opt/4/4/data/456/
     - /opt/5/5/data/567/
     - /opt/6/6/data/678/
 tasks:
  
  - name: Chek path opt
    stat: 
      path:  '{{ item }}'
    loop: '{{ array_path }}'
    register: path_is_true
    
  - name: Print path_is_true
    debug:  
      var: item.path
    loop: '{{ array_path }}'
    when:  

  - name:  Copy a file to array_path
    ansible.builtin.copy:
      src: myfile.txt
      dest: '{{ item }}'
      owner: lord
      group: lord
      mode: '0755'
      backup: yes
    loop: '{{ array_path }}'  
    when:
```

idk how to correctly initiate 'when'.
maybe there are some other errors in the playbook

Comment: i need copy myfile.txt to exist path from array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i resolved

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - stat: path={{mypath}}
      loop:
        - /opt/1/1/data/123/
        - /opt/2/2/data/234/
        - /opt/3/3/data/345/
        - /opt/4/4/data/456/
        - /opt/5/5/data/567/
        - /opt/6/6/data/678/
      loop_control:
        loop_var: mypath
      register: foo

 - name:  Copy a file to array_path
    ansible.builtin.copy:
      src: myfile.txt
      dest: '{{ item.mypath}}'
      owner: lord
      group: lord
      mode: '0755'
      backup: yes
    loop: '{{ foo.results }}'
    when: item.stat.exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the simplified list

```yaml
  array_path:
    - /tmp/opt/A
    - /tmp/opt/B
    - /tmp/opt/C
```

and the directories on the remote hosts

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 find /tmp/opt
/tmp/opt
/tmp/opt/A
/tmp/opt/B
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_13 find /tmp/opt
/tmp/opt
/tmp/opt/C
/tmp/opt/A
```

Get the status

```yaml
    - stat:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ array_path }}"
      register: array_path_stat
```

and select the existing directories by declaring the variable

```yaml
  array_path_exist: "{{ array_path_stat.results|selectattr('stat.exists') }}"
```

Use this list in the loop

```yaml
    - copy:
        src: /tmp/myfile.txt
        dest: "{{ item.item }}"
      loop: "{{ array_path_exist }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************
changed: [test_11] => (item=/tmp/opt/A)
changed: [test_13] => (item=/tmp/opt/A)
changed: [test_13] => (item=/tmp/opt/C)
changed: [test_11] => (item=/tmp/opt/B)
```

The file */tmp/myfile.txt* was copied to the remote hosts

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 find /tmp/opt
/tmp/opt
/tmp/opt/A
/tmp/opt/A/myfile.txt
/tmp/opt/B
/tmp/opt/B/myfile.txt
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_13 find /tmp/opt
/tmp/opt
/tmp/opt/C
/tmp/opt/C/myfile.txt
/tmp/opt/A
/tmp/opt/A/myfile.txt
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    array_path:
      - /tmp/opt/A
      - /tmp/opt/B
      - /tmp/opt/C

    array_path_exist: "{{ array_path_stat.results|selectattr('stat.exists') }}"

  tasks:

    - stat:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ array_path }}"
      register: array_path_stat

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: array_path_stat
        - debug:
            var: array_path_exist
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - copy:
        src: /tmp/myfile.txt
        dest: "{{ item.item }}"
      loop: "{{ array_path_exist }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
```